# Deploy an app to phone

Tags: vb.net

I wanted to test a calculator program I built in vb.net on my phone. I wanted to see if mouse click was the same as a touchscreen. So with my calculator, I have the executable files from the build folder, but how do you get it on your phone?

Comment: Do you have a Windows Phone?

Comment: Android is that the same, sorry I guess I'm getting old

Comment: @codeMonger123: No.  Android is not Windows.  To develop for your phone, start with some Android development tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run an application created with VB.NET on a phone running Android. If you like Visual Basic 6 there is a language called B4A (formerly known as Basic4Android). It is eerily similar to VB6 (although you will have to learn some phone specific things) and allows you to write Basic code and create it into an Android app. It has a fairly active community around it for such a niche product. You can find more info here: https://www.b4x.com/

Comment: Is it possible to write vb.net to a windows tablet the same way as a pc?

Comment: Yes. Writing for a tablet is always different, but a Windows tablet is basically a Windows PC without a keyboard.

Comment: Thanks I know it's a silly question, but I was thinking about writing a .net app with touch screen for a small buisness

Comment: Doesn't seem that odd of a question. You seem to be a bit lacking in knowledge of all the different platforms and what they are capable of but writing a .net app for a windows tablet is certainly possible

Answer (score 1):

Phones do not run desktop applications.  For the most part the CPUs are different architectures (x86/Intel on desktop, and ARM on mobile devices), and the operating systems are not the same as well.

That said, you have some options.

- [Xamarin](https://xamarin.com) is a commercial (paid) development tool kit for cross architecture/OS development.
- For Windows Phone only: there's the new [UWP (Universal Windows Platform)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn726767.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that will net you develop apps to run on Windows Phone *and* Windows desktop.

As of this moment in time you can not deploy a Windows desktop Console App or WinForms app to a phone.